# db2_fetch_assoc() fails midway through iterating over result set

Tags: php, ibm-midrange, db2-400, iseries-navigator

I'm running on IBM i (an AS/400) V7R2, PHP v5.6.5, Zend Server v8.0.2.

I have a query which takes less than a second to execute from iNavigator.  When I run the same query from a PHP script and then loop through it using:

```
$numRows = 0;
while ($row = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt))
{
//Do stuff
$numRows++;
}
echo $numRows++;
```

`$numRows` ends up only being a fraction of the expected result set and I get this error in the Zend logs:

```
PHP Warning:  db2_fetch_assoc(): Fetch Failure in /path/to/script.php on line XXX
```

Note that the value of $numRows varies every time I run it.  It is almost like it is timing out and ending before it can iterate through all of the result sets, but the page loads in seconds.  Outside of results missing from the result set everything seems to function and load perfectly fine on the page.

Does anyone know what might be contributing to this behavior?

Comment: Are their joblog messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Buck Calabro got me on the right track.  The issue wasn't decimal data errors but rather a sub-query in the view definition which was returning more than 1 row.  So it was a "Result of select more than one row" error.

If I did a simple `SELECT * FROM VIEW1` in iNavigator or PHP everything seemed to come up fine.  It wasn't until I either ran the mentioned query in `STRSQL` or ran the view definition manually as if it weren't part of a view in iNavigator that the error would be reported.

To help future users here is basically what was happening.

`TABLEA` contains a single column with 10 rows.
I write a view such as this:

```
CREATE VIEW VIEWA (COL1, COL2, COL3)
AS SELECT 1, 2, (
    SELECT * FROM TABLEA
);
```

The sub-select is returning 10 rows and the DB engine doesn't know how to handle it.  If instead you add `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` as part of the sub-query the error is fixed.  That isn't to say logically you will get the correct results though, since you may need the 2nd row not the first.  Second it would also be suggested you specify an `ORDER BY` and/or `WHERE` clause to ensure the first (and only) row returned would be what you want.

Comment: The problem is that _contextually_, the subselect that was coded [as an expression of a expression\column-list of a SELECT] must be a **scalar subselect** but the result of that subquery is not a single [row] value. Typically the relational data will be protected by constraints that prevent multiple rows for a query that depends on a scalar subselect; as noted, because unordered FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY may not select the desired row, the ORDER BY [and\or WHERE] clause may suffice when the constraints on the data either can or do not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that the data has errors?  One possibility is decimal data errors.

Comment: There are decimal values in the view being queried.  I'll try running the query with a particular sort order and see if I notice it stopping at the same record(s).  Previously I had not applied a sort order so maybe this is accounting for the varying number of results.  I supposed it is possible the ibm_db2 driver could be failing to this even though PHP normally wouldn't.

Comment: This sometimes happens on a legacy database when the actual contents of the numeric columns contains non-numeric characters.  The biggest culprit is blanks instead of zeroes.  Ask your database people if the table you're working with might have decimal data errors.  They'll know what you're talking about.

Comment: Another common culprit (not saying that it applies here, necessarily, just one more thing worth checking when interfacing with data from IBM i and its predecessors) is negative numbers, particularly in "zoned decimal" fields. Some tools do not know how to handle the sign nibble, which has two quirky properties: It's in the *least* significant byte, and it makes that "digit" look like a letter or a right curly brace.

Comment: @BuckCalabro thank you for your guidance.  While it wasn't a data decimal error you got me on the right track.  I'm going to joint accept your answer and mine once I'm able to (I have to wait a day).

Comment: Accept your answer - it's the correct one for this problem.  Thank you for posting that answer - it will help future seekers.